# Solving three inequalities with three variables

Tags: inequality

I wish to show that the following three inequalities are impossible to satisfy, under the constraint that one and only one variable is allowed to be negative. 
The inequalities are:
\begin{align}
\ adf & < 0 \tag{1}\\ 
\ a + d + f & < 0 \tag{2}\\
\ ad + af + df & > 0 \tag{3}\\
\end{align}
where $a<0$ and $d,f>0$. The variables are all real numbers ($a, d, f \in \mathbb R$).

I tried doing it by isolating $a$ in $(3)$ and then inserting $(2)$ after also isolating $a$ here. So from
$$a > \dfrac {-df}{d+f}$$ and $$a < -(d+f),$$
which gave me
$$-(d + f) > \dfrac {-df}{d+f},$$ then multiplying with $d+f$ gave
$$-( d^2 + f^2 +2df) > -df,$$ which results in
$$d^2 + f^2 + df < 0.$$
The last line is impossible, so it must be impossible to have one of the three variables negative and the other two positive. 
Are the method and the steps correct?

Edit: We also have the inequality 
$$2adf + a^2(d+f) + d^2(a+f) + f^2(a+d) < 0.$$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! For clarity please use $\LaTeX$ to write your equations and inequalities and use more paragraphs. You can read [How can I format maths here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Your method and steps are correct; I tested some numbers with your constraints and at least one (or two) of the inequalities fail, especially the second equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your solution is correct.

Alternatively, from $(3)$:
$$ad+af+df>0 \iff a+d>-\frac{ad}{f}$$
Add $f$ to both sides:
$$a+d+f>-\frac{ad}{f}+f$$
Consider this with $(2)$:
$$0>a+d+f>-\frac{ad}{f}+f \Rightarrow 0>-\frac{ad}{f}+f \Rightarrow f^2-ad<0 \Rightarrow \\
\underbrace{f^2}_{>0}+\underbrace{(-ad)}_{>0}<0.$$
The contradiction shows that the the system of inequalities does not have a solution for the given constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof looks correct. Strictly speaking, you should start with the
assumption that $a < 0$ and $d, f \ge 0$, but $(1)$ then implies that
$d, f > 0$.

An alternative is to note that the expressions
$$ 
 a+d+f \, , \quad ad + af + df \, , \quad adf
$$
are the [“elementary symmetric polynomials”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial)
of $a, d, f$, and that suggests to consider the polynomial 
$$
 p(x) = (x-a)(x-d)(x-f) = x^3 - (a+d+f)x^2 + (ad + af + df) x - adf \, .
$$
The given inequalities imply that
$p$ has only  positive coefficients, so that all real roots must be
negative. It follows that  $a, d, f$ are *all* negative.

Comment: I must say that I am impressed. The task was actually to prove that $a, d, f$ must be negative for the real part of the roots to be negative without using the factorization of the polynomial. We should rather (naïvely) use Routh-Hurwitz criterion to show this.